# w3schools xPath example

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

First of all I just want say Im new to xPath and after following this [xPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_examples.asp) I'm having some trouble run a flew examples given by w3chools locally (localhost) using Aptana Studio, the example runs good in their site but not so good in localhost.

When I run any [example](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryit.asp?filename=try_xpath_select_cdnodes) Im always receiving this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'evaluate' of null

The problem is here:

```
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
    var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var result = nodes.iterateNext();
```

[books.xml](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/books.xml)

Comment: What is `xml` in your example code?

Comment: The same is their example

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: @rm596: Their code makes an AJAX call.  Do you have the `books.xml`?  Are you running this code from a (local) webserver?

Comment: yes I have the books.xml file

Comment: @rm596: Are you running it from a webserver (eg WAMP)?  You cannot make AJAX calls if you are opening the files via `file:///`.

Comment: Im running from Aptana Studio that uses wamp Yes!

Comment: `xml` is `null` in your code, according to the error message you are receiving.

Comment: Yes you are correct @KevinB, the problem is in that line

Comment: So, figure out why it is null. You haven't provided the code you are using to define `xml`.

Comment: If you're using the code from the w3fools site you linked to, that suggests your path to books.xml is incorrect, or it isn't a valid xml doc.

Comment: The code is absolutely equal in their site!! I provide the link

Comment: @rm596: But does the `books.xml` file exist on *your* site in the same place?  Check your network tab your devtools.  Do you see the AJAX request?  What does it return?

Comment: Yes!! the books.xml file exist and is in the same folder

Comment: @John, there is no clear consensus about that. Please read [Discouraging w3schools as a resource](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87678/164403) and [Blacklist w3schools (with a helpful message)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156744/164403), among others.

Comment: @rm596 if it was, you wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: @rm596: So, can you access `books.xml` if you enter the URL in your web browser?  Do you see the AJAX request for it in your devtools when you run this code?

Comment: @RocketHazmat the problem was in xml file declaration <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8""?> If you put your answer i accepted

Comment: See the xml code in this link http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_examples.asp